# Can't make three20 TTPhotoViewController rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, three20

I have a `UITabBarController` application and for every tab I have a `UINavigationController`.

On one tab and further down a navigation controller I have a `TTPhotoViewController`

It works just fine except for the fact that it won't rotate.

I understood that the UIBarTabController and UINavigationController must be subclassed and must have overriden shouldAutoRotate .. Is this so? If yes, could you please give more details about this? The examples are rare and the api doc is very poor.

Comment: have you came to any solution for your problem?

Comment: hello AhmadTk, no i haven't. I just rotate the scrollView.. it's built in.